# Cannot locate PDF file in iPhone

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

In one of my activity, I displayed a PDF using WebView on screen and tried to save this PDF using this code:

```
_pageSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    NSString *newPDFName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:newPDFName];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPath, CGRectZero, nil);
     NSLog(@"path=%@",pdfPath);
```

When I run this code in iOS simulator (using Xcode) and show the path and I opened this PDF file successfully in documents folder, but when I run this code in an iPhone, I got this path:

> /var/mobile/Applications/0AF98361-C8DF-4C35-9E9F-EE48555185BC/Library/354746396.pdf

So where are PDF files stored in iPhone?

Comment: pls solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my coding is right but i will not find the pdf file.i will solve my problem.i will find my pdf file in device.
there are two ways to find the pdf file.
1)install the iexplorer filemanager software.than open document folder.
2)connect your device in to the mac.select window menu and click the device in xcode.than after select your device name.select your app.

[image]

select show container.than after you can see the document folder....

Answer (score 3):

> "..InDomains(**NSLibraryDirectory**, NSUserDomainMask, YES);"
>
> "../**Library**/354746396.pdf"

Your paths is looking in the `NSLibraryDirectory`, it should be looking in the `NSDocumentDirectory` like this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

If still fail, try this code:

```
NSString *documents = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *savePath = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.pdf"];
NSLog(@"savePath: %@", savePath);
```

Comment: i will try this code. i get this path /var/mobile/Applications/A42EA482-C921-4007-9DDF-D3181FE59177/Documents/354746393.pdf

Comment: Yes that is correct. It will work :) Let me know what happens.

Comment: yaa but how to find this pdf file in device

Comment: sorry bro but i will not find pdf file in my device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106788/discussion-between-darji-jigar-and-apptality).

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367)];
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF11.pdf"];

    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

Comment: need help for another issue